# spark streaming - kafka direct stream - Can finished batches re-run after restoring from checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, checkpoint

Consider a scenario where I've enabled concurrent jobs, so my batches could execute in any order and not wait for previous batches to finish. So, what happens when my driver failure occurs while my batch at time t is still executing and the batch at t+1 has already finished execution. Assuming that checkpointing is enabled, does my job just launch only one job for the pending batch at time t? and not bother about the batch at time t+1? Or does it consider the batch at time t+1 also as incomplete? I'm interested in knowing this because, I would like my output operations on the stream to write data in the same order as in my input.

Comment: Care to elaborate on _"a scenario where I've enabled concurrent jobs"_? How would you enable concurrent jobs in Spark Streaming?

Comment: Hi, please check the **"ConcurrentJobs Parameter :"**  section of this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spark-streaming-performance-tuning-mesos-kafka-chandan-prakash

Comment: Hi @JacekLaskowski , does the question make sense to you now? Any ideas on what could be the behavior in such a case?